# php preg match a string ignoring white space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hello I need to change this expression so it ignores white space

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z\s]{2,}\,\s)+(RED|BLUE|GREEN|BLACK)$/i",$query, $matches))

$query = "Honda Accord, RED"
```

so it still gets the match even if there is white space added such as;

```
$query = "   Honda    Accord   ,    RED   "
```

Basically i need the matches back as Honda Accord, RED with correct spacing. As you can see im no regexp expert:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "   Honda    Accord   ,    RED   "; 
$query = trim($query); // remove spaces at the ends //
$query = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $query); // make sure there aren't multiple spaces //
$query = preg_replace('/\s?,\s?/', ', ', $query); // enforce the 'word, word' format //
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z\s]{2,}\,\s)+(RED|BLUE|GREEN|BLACK)$/i",$query, $matches);
```

This formats your string so that it will have a standard form, but if you just want to get the matches it is sufficient to add `\s*` where needed.

Comment: Thanks, not quite right but i worked it out. I already had the trim ( $query ) - the preg_match works but the trick was to do the preg_repace on the $matches after -- not before. Doh!

Comment: I tested it and for the example you supplied it worked fine in this form.

Comment: Thanks again Alin yes it worked but i also have query like Ford, RED so i had to make it work for that as well. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need whitespace before and after color and also at the beginning:

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z\s]{2,},\s)+\s*(RED|BLUE|GREEN|BLACK)\s*$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/cDlBKXjN1u)